# Heroku server instances, session affinity and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a functioning webApp that uses socket.io to communicate to a node.js server and ultimately to other clients. When moving into large scale testing, if Heroku initiates a new dyno to run my webApp, how can socket.io connect to the new instances and if I have local data stored in one dyno, can another dyno access the same data?

Example: When a client connects to the server a new global object is created that stores information as key/value pairs. If the global object already exists, when a new client connects they are able to access the global object. If a client connects to a dyno different than the dyno where the original object was created can they access it?

I have read through Heroku documentation including the section on 'Session Affinity' but I'm still confused/uncertain as to how it works.

Thanks All

Comment: "local data stored in one dyno" is antithetical to [Heroku's design principles](https://12factor.net/)